# How do I check if a submit is clicked, so my function will not trigger?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

I am working on an image upload site. When the user uploads the images with no problems, it save the image in 4 different sizes inside 4 different folders. After that, they are redirected to same page with new content. Now they are going to crop the image. The Image crop functions work fine. I've made a function to check if the user leaves the site. If they do, the 3 functions will delete the 4 stored images by an AJAX script.

Code:

```
function unfinished(album, img) {
    window.onbeforeunload = function(e) {
        e = e || window.event;
        var response = '';
        var xmlhttp;
        if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
            // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
            xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        } else {
            // code for IE6, IE5
            xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
                response = xmlhttp.responseText;
            }
        }
        xmlhttp.open("GET", "incl/unfinished.php?a=" + album + "&i=" + img, true);
        xmlhttp.send();
        // For IE and Firefox prior to version 4
        if (e) {
            e.returnValue = response;
        }
        // For Safari
        return response;
    }
}
```

My problem is, that this function is also triggered when they click the "save crop" button. And of course it's not what I want.

Any solutions to how to make the function not popup when the save button is clicked?

If it matters, I run the unfinished function by:

```
onload='onfinished("$nameonalbum","Filename")'
```

My save  crop html code:

```
input type="submit" name="upload_thumbnail" value="Save crop" id="save_thumb"
```

Any help is welcome. Thank you for the patience and understanding.

Comment: unload triggers on ANY attemp to leave a page, which includes form submission. You'll have to update the logic in the unload to check HOW the unload was triggered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to do something similar to you in one case, so I created a variable `unload = true` and the start of the page, and then instead of doing `<input type="submit"` I changed it to `<input type="button" onclick="runFunction();"` and then in my

```
function runFunction() {
unload = false;
$('#form').submit();
};
```

then I would add `if(unload) { ...do stuff here }` in the `onBeforeUnload()`

Answer (score 1):

Current process flow is complicated due to Ajax request and event handling.

You can change the process to following.

1. user uploads image at `upload.php`
2. `upload.php`

   1. Creates 4 versions of the original image
   2. Marks these images as `NOT_CROPPED` in db somewhere with TIMESTAMP
   3. Delete any NOT_CROPPED type images in db whose TIMESTAMP is older than `1 day`. Define this duration yourself.
3. `upload.php` load back with new cropping tool visible
4. On Submit all the 4 Images' state is update to `COMPLETE`.

Comment: Thanks. I'll see what i can create with the given information from you. 
Kind regards Frederik